# How to reduce bitterness in silken tofu 'cream' soup?

Tags: soup, tofu

I made a 'cream' soup using silken tofu,  vegetarian soup stock, (pre-packaged) fried onions, and a bit of white balsamic vinegar.  It was pretty good but had a bitterness at the back of the palate.  What can I do to remedy that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/13016/counter-to-bitterness-in-soup).

Comment: Chopped cilantro - i.e., if you like cilantro as much as I do. Shiitake mushrooms, sliced carrots and fresh sweet onions rather than packaged fried onions. Perhaps, it was the packaged onions that have gone stale.

Answer (score 2):

The bitterness was likely due to one of two things: the vegetarian soup stock or the packaged fried onions.  The stock would be a like candidate if you used a concentrate or boullion, rather than stock-in-a-box, which tends to be too sweet, if anything.  Otherwise, look to the fried onions; if the ones you used are burnt or rancid, they would add an unpleasant bitterness to anything you added them to.  Try tasting the ingredients individually until you locate the bitter flavor, and then swap in a better quality ingredient.